# Laravel 5.1 - Authentication - When user is logged off, the home does not redirect to the login page

Tags: laravel

As the official Laravel 5.1 docs say:

> When a user is not successfully authenticated, they will be redirected to the /auth/login URI.

And, also:

> When a user is successfully authenticated, they will be redirected to the /home URI, which you will need to register a route to handle.

This is the code I wrote for the /home URI:

```html
// Home
Route::get('/home', function() {
return view('auth/main');
});
```

So, now, when I visit /home, or auth/main, why I'm not redirected to the login page?

Please help!

Comment: Do you have the auth middleware attached to the route? This can be done in the controller or in the routes file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `main.blade.php` file under auth folder try this

```
Route::get('/home', function() {
    return view('auth.main');
});
```

Comment: Hi! I tried but it doesn't work! Also, what's the difference between using points or slashes?

Comment: In laravel you should use point to separate files in nested file structure.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to @ujiriukiri.

I wrote this code:

```
Route::get('/home', ['middleware' => 'auth', function() {
return view('auth.main'); }]);
```

... and now it works for /home, but not for auth/main. How to solve?